# Fork jQuery to fork one of its built-in components as a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, github, fork

I want to make my own enhanced spin-off of one of the jQuery "helper" functions as a plugin (`deferred.js`/`$.when()` as it happens.)

Well actually I've already made it, but completely detached from any source code repository.

What I want to ask is since jQuery uses GitHub, and GitHub seems to promote forking projects, what is the best way to go about making my plugin in a way that I can eventually share with others or offer back to jQuery etc?

**Should I fork the entire jQuery project and convert the one source file into a new plugin project?**

I really don't know anything much about the Git/GitHub ways of doing things but it seems I can't just fork the one source file but need to fork the entire jQuery. If I'm making a plugin I won't be needing all the rest anyway.

Or should I just copy and paste the one source file without leaving a "paper trail" between my derived project and the original project?

(If this question belongs on programmers.SE instead I'm perfectly fine with migrating it. If the question is totally wrong for SO let me know if there's any way I can fix it since I think this is a topic that would be useful for others.)

Comment: I think it is ok here.  Programmers is more for conceptual questions.  This is quite a practical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this would be better suited as a standalone jQuery plugin, mostly because you can maintain your code separately from the main jQuery library. I would make it just another script to include after a user includes jQuery.js and set up my own github repo for it.

You're right, you can't just fork one file because forking is for branches, conceptually speaking.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I do just want to make a standalone jQuery plugin, but conceptually I'm making a fork of `$.when()` so I want to know if "doing it properly" would be a real fork, even though I can't fork just a function or just a source file but need to fork the whole project. Would it be rude for me to evolve `$.when()` into something else in such a way that there's no "history" to follow through the Git(Hub) system from my evolved version to its original ancestor? (Am I making sense? \-:)

Comment: Hm.. I'm not sure I follow 100%. I think your concern is that you're not actually making a fork, so there'd be no real way to see where you're forking from, such as GitHub's history shows during a normal fork?

I'd suggest documenting heavily, in this case. In your README, I'd say you can link up each version of your plugin with the version of jQuery you're basing off.

Comment: I guess that's it. I don't really know all the reasons / best practices / terminology with modern source code repos. I never used much besides commit and update on the various systems I've been exposed to but these day branching and forking etc seems to be much more common and promoted ... but I missed a lot of that coming about. Thanks for your answer and comments though!

Comment: @hippietrail No problem. You may want to read up some more on git, github, and VCSes, in general. It's never too late ;)